# How to extract a mp3 from an FLV file using Java?

Tags: java, mp3, flv

I've searched the internet/StackOverflow pretty well yet can't seem to find a complete code walkthrough of how to do it. I've read about FFmpeg and Xuggle and they look promising however this is my scenario:

1) Users on a website create a post and attach a URL (EX: a youtube link)

2) When they submit, a script on the server will extract the audio from the FLV and then write the file to be stored on a database.

Looking for just some raw Java code I can play around with on my local machine while I try to get the forms and dbase setup.

Thanks for any information you might be able to provide. Also if you believe I'm approaching the situation the completely wrong way, do tell!

Answer (score 1):

JDownloader do that job. You can see their source code in [svn://svn.jdownloader.org/jdownloader/trunk](http://svn://svn.jdownloader.org/jdownloader/trunk)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your bigger challange is to get the FLV itself. The player might get it over RTMP you have to implement it and mimic how the player talks to the media server.